# How to create Snowflake function and return int value

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im building this function in Snowflake, but it giving me the error "compilation failed".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_TestFunction ("StartDate" DATE, "EndDate" DATE)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS'
BEGIN
    DECLARE RES INTEGER;
    
    IF (:StartDate IS NOT NULL AND :EndDate IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            :=RES = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN "BusinessDay" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN "BusinessDay" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 1 END
        FROM
            DBO."DATE_TABLE"
        WHERE
            Date BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
    END

    RETURN :RES
';
```

Comment: Hi - if you have a look at the CREATE FUNCTION documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-function it should be clear what’s wrong with your code. For a start, you're missing at least one required statement in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to copy paste a UDF from another database to Snowflake.

A similar SQL UDF in Snowflake that compiles would look like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_TestFunction (StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
$$
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN "BusinessDay" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN "BusinessDay" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 1 END
        FROM
            -- (select 1 "BusinessDay", '2020-01-01' date)
            DBO."DATE_TABLE"
        WHERE
            Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
$$;
```

But going over all the differences between Snowflake SQL UDFs and the unspecified source of this UDF would get out of scope for this question.

For a general overview, check the docs for SQL UDFs in Snowflake and for SQL Stored Procedures.